# automating forms in access with Uipath

Tags: automation, ui-automation, uipath

I have built a access form that runs several queries. I have to invoke these queries through a button press (1 and 2). Either button will run one query for a dynamic period of time. When the query finishes, a popup window will appear and then I click okay to repeat the process on the second button.

I haven’t run this yet as its a proof of concept on a small “live database”.

my steps are as follows,

- click radio button
- use `On Element Appear` to wait for pop up window
- click the OK button
- click second radio button
- use `On Element Appear` to wait for pop up window
- click the OK button

my question is, will my nesting work as it is now? having the “click” radio button(s) outside of the `On Element Appear` activities?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either make use of the `On Element Appear` activity, which will act as a container, or use the `Find Element` activity, as you already stated that the Popup Window will appear as soon as your query finishes. Depending on the time required for the query to complete you may or may not need to increase the `TimeoutMS` property, which defaults to 30 seconds.

I would recommend starting with the Desktop Recorder, and then change selectors and properties accordingly if required.